# Flutter app size increased due to too many audios

Tags: java, android, flutter, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am working on a Flutter application and I have more than **100 sounds** that users can play for educational purposes.

I am not using any server or Firebase. Every audio is almost **1 MB**. With that assets folder size will be more than **100** and app size will increase too.

Can I store all the audio in the SQLite Database? Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you try verifying the size using the [flutter app size tool](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/app-size) and add the screenshot.

Comment: try to compress your audio files and reduce the sizes. or use remote link to use files. you can use google drive like storage if you like

Comment: @Anushka then it will not work offline. Actually, the app is for children's educational purposes and it is offline. Can't I store the audio in SQLite as a blob?

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your audio files using the `flutter_sound` package, it'll help you to decrease the size of your audio files, and don't forget to run `flutter clean` before compiling your app, unless your app size will be more than that size that you expect to be.

Comment: sorry, I did not get you. You are saying I should use the ```flutter_sound``` package for playing audio or I should use it for compressing? btw I am using ```assets_audio_player``` for playing audio.

Comment: I mean you should use it for compressing bro, you can take a look at the documentation of this package to get the point -> https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound